# Re-Factor duplicate dictionary Logic in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

Is there a better way? How to avoid the duplicate dictionary logic and put it in a generic method?

```
enum department { IT, CSE, MECH, EEE, ECE }
    Dictionary<department, decimal> collegeDepartmentDecimal = new Dictionary<department, decimal>
    {
        {department.IT, 1},
        {department.CSE, 45},
        {department.MECH, 66},
        {department.EEE, 72},
        {department.ECE, 75},
    };

    Dictionary<department, string> collegeDepartmentString = new Dictionary<department, string>
    {
       {department.IT, "YES"},
        {department.CSE, "NO"},
        {department.MECH, "NULL"},
        {department.EEE, "N/A"},
        {department.ECE, null},
    };
```

I am using dictionary for this purpose.

```
decimal d = ("something" == collegeDepartmentDecimal[collegeDepartmentDecimal.IT] ? collegeDepartmentString[collegeDepartmentDecimal.CSE] : "something");
```

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: I suspect your problem could be more elegantly solved by [using attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: I should have been more specific. Typo Err. Not generics, just generic. Now, I have modified the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean by refactoring using generics?

If you want to store all this information in one dictionary you can either a) use System.Tuple b) Use some value type to store information

a)

```
Dictionary<department, Tuple<decimal, string>> collegeDepartmentDecimalAndString = new Dictionary<department, Tuple<decimal, string>>
{
    {department.IT, Tuple.Create(1m, "YES")},
    {department.CSE, Tuple.Create(45m, "NO")},
    {department.MECH, Tuple.Create(66m, "NULL")},
    {department.EEE, Tuple.Create(72m, "N/A")},
    {department.ECE, Tuple.Create(75m, "")},
};
```

Comment: How do I access 1st item (item1) from dictionary? decimal d = ("something" == beneficiaryDecimalAndStringDictionary[collegeDepartmentDecimal.IT] ? beneficiaryDecimalAndStringDictionary[collegeDepartmentDecimal.CSE] : "something");

Comment: There is no "first" item in dictionary, but if you look at it from the standpoint of IEnumerable you can use Enumerable.First or Enumerable.FirstOrDefault extension methods

Comment: When I use "var lowHighPrice = Tuple.Create(21.5, 23.0);" I can extract like this var low = lowHighPrice.Item1;
var high = lowHighPrice.Item2; So, How do I do  it my case? Because, FirstOrDefault won't help

Comment: I figured out. It has to be beneficiaryDecimalAndStringDictionary[collegeDepartmentDecimal.IT].Item1

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit from the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`class as follows :

```
public class MyDictionary<department, TValue> : Dictionary<department, TValue>
{
    public MyDictionary() : base() { }
    public MyDictionary(int capacity) : base(capacity) { }
}
```

then use it as :

```
MyDictionary<department, decimal> dic1 = new MyDictionary<department, decimal>() {
    {department.IT, 1},
    {department.CSE, 45},
    {department.MECH, 66},
    {department.EEE, 72},
    {department.ECE, 75}
};
MyDictionary<department, string> dic2 = new MyDictionary<department, string>() {
    {department.IT, "YES"},
    {department.CSE, "NO"},
    {department.MECH, "NULL"},
    {department.EEE, "N/A"},
    {department.ECE, ""}
};
```

in your code.